# Are there examples persistent homology being used to study non-linear data?

Tags: algebraic-topology, applications, data-analysis, topological-data-analysis

You can compute the persistent homology of any point cloud embedded in a metric space. In the real-world applications of persistent homology I've come across so far, the data points all have (naturally) linear dimensions, and so the data clouds embed into $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Are there any examples of researchers using persistent homology to effectively study data sets with non-linear data? Or where the metric they have to impose on the data is not just the induced metric from $\mathbf{R}^n$? I'm looking over some of the [examples given in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1932218/167197) now to see what they've done.

Comment: I'm not an expert on topological data analysis and don't know what kinds of topologies arise, but note that any finite-dimensional manifold can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for large enough $n$ (as well as any finite dimensional compact metric space), so I think for a non-example it would need to be something infinite-dimensional (which I'm guessing doesn't happen often in data) or a rather pathological topology.

Comment: Oh yeah, [Whitney's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) for manifolds. I didn't know that you have one for metric spaces though. Do you still have to consider a higher dimensional Euclidean space to find an embedding though? In view of this then, I suppose I'm looking for a "real" example of $n$-dimensional data — each point in the data cloud has $n$ coordinates — where the individual coordinates are not linear, and (therefor?) the data cloud can't be embedded in $\mathbf{R}^n$ for that $n$.

Comment: Apparently there is a "Menger-Nöbeling theorem" which states that you can get an embedding in the same dimension as Whitney's theorem (i haven't found a decent citation, but it's mentioned in this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension#Relationship_between_dimensions)